# How to set app:icon dynamically with data binding?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have this XML:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_default"
     app:icon="@{model.actionBarData.myDynamicIcon}" />
```

And I have this method and LiveData in my model's actionBarData to set the icon programmatically:

```
private var _myDynamicIcon = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val myDynamicIcon: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _myDynamicIcon


// Called by some logic in my app

fun setMyDynamicIcon() {
    _myDynamicIcon.value = when (status) {
        status.STATUS1 -> R.drawable.icon1
        status.STATUS2 -> R.drawable.icon2
        status.STATUS3 -> R.drawable.icon3
    }
}
```

I want the icon to change when `setMyDynamicIcon` is called. However I get error:

`Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.Button app:icon> that accepts parameter type 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.lang.Integer>'`

I also tried storing a `Drawable` object in `myDynamicIcon`, this did not work either (same error but with  `Drawable` type).

How can I set the `app:icon` via data binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx @generatedAcc.x09218. Final code using Binding Adapters:

XML:

```
 <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_default"
       app:dynamicIcon="@{model.actionBarData.status}" />
```

Adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("dynamicIcon")
fun View.setDynamicIcon(status: Status?) {
    status?.let {
        val iconResource = when(status) {
            Status.STATUS1 -> R.drawable.ic_1
            Status.STATUS2 -> R.drawable.ic_2
            Status.STATUS3 -> R.drawable.ic_3
        }

        (this as MaterialButton).setIconResource(iconResource)
    }
}
```

LiveData:

```
    private var _status = MutableLiveData<Status>()
    val status: LiveData<Status>
        get() = _status

    fun setStatus(status: Status) {
        _status.value = status
    }
```

The icon changes on `setStatus` call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Binding Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic), you just need to change your `setMyDynamicIcon()` implementation a little bit(i.e., make it a binding adapter method), other code is pretty much copy/paste from the provided link and it'll work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I posted my final working code with binding adapters

Answer (score 1):

There is universal **BindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("dynamicIcon")
fun setDynamicIcon(button: MaterialButton, @DrawableRes resourceId: Int) =
    button.setIconResource(resourceId)
```

example use

```
app:dynamicIcon="@{viewModel.iconDepositButton(item)}"
```

**BONUS**

```
@BindingAdapter("dynamicIconGravity")
fun setIconGravity(button: MaterialButton, @MaterialButton.IconGravity iconGravity: Int) {
    button.iconGravity = iconGravity
}
```